# On irreducible polynomials over a field $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $K$ is a field and $f(x) \in K[x]$ such that $\deg (f) = n$. IF $f(x)$ is $\mathbf{not}$ irreducible, then $f(x)$ has a divisor of degree less than or equal to $n/2$

#### Try:

Write $f(x) \sum^n a_i x^i$. Since $f$ is not irreducible, then we can write it as a product of irreducible factors, say $f(x) = (x-c_1)...(x - c_{n/2})...(x-c_n)$. Let $g(x) = (x - c_{n/2})...(x-c_n)$ and so $\deg(g) = n/2$ and is divisor of $f$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are supposing that $n$ is even, moreover $f$ not irreducible doesn't mean completely reducible, maybe you could have some factors which are irreducible over K. For instance $x^3-1$ is reducible but not completely. Then your proof is not correct.

Comment: "...$\;x^3-1\;$ is reducible but not completely" ... *over the field* $\;\Bbb Q\;$ or  $\;\Bbb R\;$ , for example . Over $\;\Bbb C\;$ or, for example, over $\;\Bbb F_7\;$ it is completely reducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supose it is not so, then we can write $\;f=pq\;$ , with $\;\deg p\,,\,\deg q>\frac n2\;$ , but then (remember we're in a polynomial ring over a *field* **(*)**)

$$n=\deg f\stackrel{(*)}=\deg p+\deg q>\frac n2+\frac n2=n\;\;\text{contradiction}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the degree-formula:

If $f$ is reducible (not irreducible), $f$ can be written as $f=gh$ with $g,h\in K[x]$ and $\deg(g),\deg(h)\ge1$.

Since $K$ is a field (hence an integral domain) the degree-formula $\deg(f)\le\deg(g)+\deg(h)$ holds for "$=$".

So we have $n=\deg(f)={\deg(g)}+{deg(h)}$ and up to this point, you should recognize, that your statement is really trivial. With this formula we have the following:

If $1\le\deg(g)=:q\le\frac{n}{2}$, then $\deg(h)=n-q$ and $g$ is a divisor of a degree equal or less than $\frac{n}{2}$.

If $n\ge\deg(g)=:q>\frac{n}{2}$, then $1\le\deg(h)=n-q\le\frac{n}{2}$ and $h$ is a divisor of a degree equal or less than $\frac{n}{2}$.